# Try-with-resources for Base instead of DB

Tags: activejdbc

I'd like to use try-with-resources for accessing my database as my code has reached a level of complexity where it's difficult to always remember to close the database when moving between threads - I'd rather use try-with-resources.

I use the Base class, as it's advised to use this for cases where you have just one database. (http://javalite.io/database_connection_management, 'DB and Base classes' heading)

I found the documentation where it is described you can simply:

```
try(DB db = new DB()){
  db.open();
  // Wrong class, I should be using Base
}
```

However, unfortunately, this is only the case for the DB class, which it's not advised I use.

In the stack overflow reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493247/cannot-open-a-new-connection-because-existing-connection-is-still-on-current-thr) it's said I can write:

```
try(DB db = Base.open(...)){

  // Type error
}
```

However, this gives IDE error "Incompatible types. Required DB, Found Connection". If I cast Base, this results in "org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection cannot be cast to org.javalite.activejdbc.DB"

```
try(DB db = (DB) Base.open(...)){

  // ClassCastException, you can't cast Base to DB
}
```

I've also tried keeping it as a Connection, however, when the code block completes it doesn't close the resource, so I get error "Cannot open a new connection because existing connection is still on current thread, name: default"

```
try(Connection conn = Base.open(...)){

  // Doesn't close resource after completing code block
}
```

Is it possible to use try-with-resources with ActiveJDBC's Base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using class `DB` in case of just one database connection. If you look at the code of the class [Base](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/Base.java) you will see that all it does is call the class `DB` with hard-coded connection name `default`.

The recommendation to use the `Base` class  in case of one connection is simply for convenience. If it is more convenient for you  to use `DB`, then use `DB`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.